# Не срабатывает сравнение google-apps-script

Tags: javascript, циклы, google-apps-script

```
function Statistics() {
  var project = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = project.getSheetByName("жилпоселок"); 
  var sheet5 = project.getSheetByName("Статистика");
  var DB1 = sheet1.getRange("A2:K1000").getValues();
  var DB5 = sheet5.getRange("A2:A500").getValues();
  for(i = 0; i < DB1.length; ++i) {
    if (DB1[i][3] == "Конец дня") {
      sheet5.getRange(2,12).setValue(DB1[i][0]); //выводится значение 18.02.2021
      sheet5.getRange(3,12).setValue(DB5[13]); //выводится значение 18.02.2021
      for (a = 0; a < DB5.length; ++a){
        if(DB5[a] == DB1[i][0]){
          sheet5.getRange(3,11).setValue("ok"); //не происходит
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Не срабатывает второй IF, хотя данные точно между собой совпадают. Если вместо IF ставлю

```
sheet.getRange(a+2,2).setValue(DB5[a]);
```

то получаю две идентичные колонки, одна уже заполнена изначально, вторую заполняет скрипт

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

`DB5` - это двумерный массив. А Вы работаете с ним, как с одномерным. ТО есть `DB5[13]` - это не значение -а одномерный массив. Скорее всего, Вы хотели использовать `DB5[13][0]`

Update 20.02.2021
И так как выяснилось, что это даты - то через обычное сравнение (==) даты не сравниваются ( так как это объекты ). Обычно сравниваются через getTime()

Comment: Это одномерный массив, к тому же, проблема найдена и решена

Comment: getValues() возвращает двумерный массив. Почитайте документацию https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()  . И да, даты - это объекты - через обычное сравнение == они не сравниваются. Сравниваются обычно через getTime()

Comment: getValues() возвращает двумерный массив, если getRange() захватывает диапазон например А20:К30, если диапазон будет в пределах одной строки или колонки - будет одномерный массив, проверьте, если не верите.

Comment: Ух ты, в документации такого новшества не описано, видать что-то прошло мимо меня. И мимо документации:))

Comment: Прошу прощения, был неправ, действительно двумерный массив, но, если указать только DB5[13], гугл-скрипт автоматически возьмет значение DB5[13][0]

Comment: Если сделаете console.log(DB5[13]) или Array.isArray(DB5[13]) - увидите, что это именно обычный одномерный массив состоящий из 1 элемента. Автоматически преобразование массива в значение GAS ( он же JS ) не делает

Answer (score -1):

Ответ найден. Для того, чтобы работало сравнение дат, формат ячеек должен "Обычный текст". Если формат ячеек автоматический или "дата", то сравнение через IF не работает.